# Closed form from recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, closed-form, stirling-numbers

We have $a(0)=a(1)=1$,
$$a(n)=(-1)^{n-1}+2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k-1}a(k)$$
$$1,1,3,13,75,541,4683,\cdots$$
which has nice closed forms, ex.
$$a(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k!{n\brace k}$$
Related sequence $b(0)=b(1)=1$,
$$b(n)=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\binom{n}{k}-2^{n-k-1}\right]b(k)$$
$$1,1,2,6,27,166,1282,\cdots$$
unknown for OEIS.

Is there a nice closed form for it?

Comment: $a(n)=\frac{1}{2} \Phi \left(\frac{1}{2},-n,0\right)$ where $\Phi$ is HurwitzLerchPhi.

Comment: OT but did I count right that this is question #1000000?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Why is the one-million-question and what does it have in common?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Math Stackexchange counts questions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions.  And  this is the one-millionth question!

Comment: At the time when the 1-millionth question was actually posted,  a screenshot was taken, see (scroll down) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/ . So unfortunately, this was not the one. However, the numbering changes, see the discussion at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29230/identify-our-millionth-question/29242#29242

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well, I suppose this was not the 1-millionth question, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Andreas, thank you for details! I use mobile app, so there is no numeration of questions. My first reaction was thought, that it some kind of specific joke.

Comment: @Andreas. Thanks for the explanation.